# Reverse engineering of metal detector

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, analog, embedded, reverse-engineering

I am a junior electronics engineer working on a project related to a metal detector.

I am facing a problem. The signal from the op-amp (circled) is going into the analog switch (CD4066 IC, circled.) For some reason, when the signal comes to the output it is totally changed - it reverted and for some reason even changed its shape.

I don't know why this could be happening. I can fix the signal by placing a 10K resistor on the switch output to 12V - the signal becomes like an input but the second wave stays there. It should not be there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried simulating it?

Comment: Where exactly are the two measurements made? What is the enable input doing during these measurements?

Comment: Perhaps U2A is always off and the signal you see is actually what is happening at pin 9 of U1C. Can't see all the workings of that stage, but it could be doing all kinds of things if it is getting input from somewhere else that is not on the section of schema you  posted.

Comment: Is this a school assignment? We see quite a few "problems with my metal detector circuit" here.

Comment: For anyone interested in this topic, they might want to see the update(s) where the OP asked the same question here: [All About Circuits](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/help-reverse-engineering-a-metal-detector.180179/)

Comment: What sits on the other side of the signal from CD4066 pin 13? Did you use decoupling cap on the Vdd?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson no this is not an school assignment it is related to my work

Comment: @Lundin yes I am using decoupling capacitors power supply  is not noisy.